# How to hide not visible parts behind an addplot3 in a beamer presentation with overlays

Tags: pgfplots, tikz-3d

I use a beamer presentation with overlays to show a 3D plot with addplot3 (see MWE). In the second slide a dashed line with marks is plotted. In the third slide a surface is plotted and the part of the dashed line not visible from the point of view of the observer becomes hidden, but that does not happen with the mark at coordinate (4,4,0) that should also be hidden for the observer. How can I solve this? I want all objects that should not be visible from the point of view of the observer become hidden behind the surface. I have tried opacity=1 with the surface but nothing happens.

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

   \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.75]
   \begin{axis}[
        clip=false,
        xmax=20,ymax=20,zmax=20,xmin=0,ymin=0,zmin=0,
        grid=both,
        view/h=45,
        small,]
   \only<2->{\addplot3[dashed, color=red,mark=*,mark size=1.5pt,mark options={color=red,draw=red,fill=red}] coordinates{ (4,0,0) (4,4,0) (20,4,0) };}
   \only<3->{\addplot3[surf,samples=20,domain=0:20, y domain=0:20,opacity=1]{x^(0.5) * y^(0.5)};}
   \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The marks are on special layers by default. One option is use `mark layer=like plot` (and to put the plot on an appropriate layer) as in

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Mark layers can be tricky}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.75]
   \begin{axis}[
        clip=false,
        xmax=20,ymax=20,zmax=20,xmin=0,ymin=0,zmin=0,
        grid=both,
        view/h=45,
        small,small,set layers,
        mark layer=like plot]
   \begin{pgfonlayer}{pre main}         
   \only<2->{\addplot3[dashed, color=red,mark=*,mark size=1.5pt,mark options={color=red,draw=red,fill=red}] coordinates{ (4,0,0) (4,4,0) (20,4,0) };}
   \end{pgfonlayer}
   \only<3->{\addplot3[surf,samples=20,domain=0:20, y domain=0:20,opacity=1]{x^(0.5) * y^(0.5)};}
   \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]